# CoreData refreshAllObjects() does not refresh all objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios-app-group

We have three separate apps which are in same App Group and access the same CoreData store. Problem is that when I change something in item in `NSOrderedSet` from relationship in managed object, save go to another app where refresh is performed, changed data are not there.

We are using `NSPersistentContainer` and only one context in each app,  `container.newBackgroundContext()` saved to property in singleton. For each app when app goes to BG `save()` is performed on that context and when app goes to FG `refreshAllObjects()` is called on the context.

When I change some basic attribute in managed object it is changed properly in another app. But when I change some property in item from NSSet which is a relationship on managed object this change is not visible in another app.

While I was debugging I tried to call fetch but it also provides only old data. Only when I called `context.reset()` and then fetch again it returns valid new data.

Problem is that I cannot use reset on whole context because I will lose all registered objects in app.

Is this valid behavior or bug that referenced objects changes are not applied when `refreshAllObjects()` is used?

Is there any way how to force fetch request to get data directly from the database and not cached one from context?

Comment: Have you tried [refresh(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506224-refresh) rather than refreshAllObjects()?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes I tried use just `refresh` on whole object but it did not work as well. It also check boolean values of `hasChanges` on context as well as on managed object. But these are only indicating local unsaved changes as mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution to my problem. I was able to force fetch to fetch directly from persistence (not from context) by setting [shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506440-shouldrefreshrefetchedobjects) property of `NSFetchRequest` to `true`.

I was not able to find a solution to just refresh already fetched objects - but this way I was able to get fresh data using new fetch at least.

Comment: I have a similar setup as you and I added this property to my request in my NSFetchedResultsController and it didn't refresh the objects. Do you have any example code?